# During "p4 copy" does perforce update the integration history

Tags: perforce

Problem Statement:
There are two P4 branches MAIN and DEV. 
Their current integration history is not known.
If we do a "p4 copy" from MAIN-->DEV, all the previous integration history becomes irrelevant. So when we do a "p4 integrate" in either direction, there should be 0 integrations. 
Is this assumption correct?

In practice when I tried this, the P4 Merge/Integrate preview showed pending integrations, after I did a P4 copy from MAIN-->DEV. That did not make sense to me.

Please could someone clarify this?

Thanks.
Paul V.

Comment: And after you did the `p4 resolve`, and looked at `p4 resolved`, did the situation become easier to understand?

Answer (score 0):

During a `p4 copy`, integration history is largely(*) irrelevant, because `p4 copy` operates primarily on the basis of whether the head revisions of the source and target are identical.  This means that:

1. Files with no integration history that happen to be identical will not be touched.
2. Files with full integration history that are not identical (e.g. files where specific changes have been "ignored" to permit controlled divergence) will be copied over.

During a `p4 copy`/`p4 submit`, normal integration history is created **for the affected files**.

---

During a `p4 merge` or `p4 integrate`, content is irrelevant, because `p4 merge` operates solely on the basis of the integration history.  This means that:

1. Files with no integration history that happen to be identical will be opened for integrate.  At the time of `p4 resolve` (when the content is actually diffed and merged) these will auto-resolve as "copy" actions.
2. Files with full integration history that are not identical (e.g. files where specific changes have been "ignored" to permit controlled divergence) will not be opened for integrate.

---

Note that in case (1), a file will be skipped by `copy`, and then subsequently opened for resolve by `merge`.  In practice this is not generally an inconvenience since identical files are always trivial to `resolve`.

Regardless, if this particular scenario perturbs you and you want to avoid it, you can use the `-f` flag on copy, which forces a hybrid behavior -- for files that are identical, `copy` will internally do the equivalent of a `merge -n` to check the integration history, and then redundantly copy those files in order to establish new integration history for the benefit of later merges.

```
% p4 help copy

    copy -- Copy one set of files to another

    p4 copy [options] fromFile[rev] toFile
    p4 copy [options] -b branch [-r] [toFile[rev] ...]
    p4 copy [options] -b branch -s fromFile[rev] [toFile ...]
    p4 copy [options] -S stream [-P parent] [-F] [-r] [toFile[rev] ...]

        options: -c changelist# -f -n -v -m max -q

        'p4 copy' copies one set of files (the 'source') into another (the
        'target').

        ...

        The -f flag forces the creation of extra revisions in order to
        explicitly record that files have been copied.  Deleted source files
        will be copied if they do not exist in the target, and files that are
        already identical will be copied if they are not connected by existing
        integration records.
```

---

(*) Notable exceptions: the `-f` behavior described above, and some edge cases around `+k` (keyword-expanded) files where "spurious" content differences are compensated for by a cursory examination of integration records to establish that the revisions are semantically identical.  In addition, for files that `copy` does open, integration history is consulted to determine how to render the revision range (the start revision doesn't actually matter for a "copy" record, but if you don't generate one that "looks right" people will ask "why do these ranges overlap?" so there's an effort to create the illusion of the copy having resulted from a merge operation in order to keep those questions to a minimum).